# Use different fonts in same Excel cell?

Tags: text, formatting, excel-2007

Is there any way to change the color and/or font of specific text within an excel cell?  That is, I'd like one part of the cell's displayed value to be red and another part of the same cell's displayed value to be blue (as an example).  Since the displayed values are being calculated as formulas, I'd need some sort of formatting formula that would apply only the stuff inside the formula.  I can't seem to find anything in the text.

Comment: Highlight Cell.  Press Ctrl+1 is your friend.

Comment: Nope, that uses the built-in excel custom formats, and in order for me to specify the condition, I'd need a custom format that evaluates formulas.  Would love to use it but can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do this based on a formula, you will have to write some VBA. See [this example](http://vbadud.wordpress.com/2007/11/03/excel-vba-change-font-color-for-part-of-text/)

Comment: Could I use the VBA technique to apply different fonts as well?

Comment: Yes. You can change any attribute. Font name and type, bold, strikethrough, etc. etc. this way. There are many VBA examples available on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

No problem. Edit the value in the formula toolbar.

Comment: Oops! Missed the part about it being a calculated value. Conditional formatting is the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [Conditional](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/questions/cond_format1.php) Formatting in excel.

[image]

Comment: I can't use conditional formatting because I want the fonts/colors to apply to specific calculated values within the cell.  I am creating an inline bar graph.  I'd like to format the bar graph using one font and the associated value using a different font.