# Multiple Excel Values in Rows into one single cell with spaces AND some in Italics. Possible? I know this is amateur but I don;t know

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rows

I want to get Rows 2-7 into Row 8 with each value on a separate line so when I copy/paste into PowerPoint it will be formatted already. How do I do this?

Also, I would need the percentages to be *Italics*. Possible?

[Image Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USJWX.jpg)

Comment: to use Formula `=TRANSPOSE(B1:B7)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand what you are looking for, but in terms of changing vertical data into horizontal/row - you can just copy it and then paste special transpose... (in the right click menu)

---

Edit: Ok so looking at the image you uploaded, as @Om3r commented you can use the Transpose function. This as far as I know, however, will not put the values into a **single** cell (though could you not copy across the value from a range of cells to powerpoint instead?).

To put into a single cell with spaces, you could use Transpose and then Concatenate the values `CONCATENATE(B8 & " " & C8 & " " ...etc)` - this will lose formatting such as italics though. This post might help for more info about setting different formats in a single cell:  [Use different fonts in same Excel cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109644/use-different-fonts-in-same-excel-cell)

*To use Transpose anyway:*

Assuming you don't need the header transposed, put `=TRANSPOSE(B2:B7)`, then in the formula bar press ctrl-shift-enter, drag out to fill the number of cells as values, and use ctrl-shift-enter again  (or copy into all the cells first, ignore the value! error which will fix once ctrl-shift-enter)

Copy/paste special method is useful for a one off, transpose if you will be updating the numbers several times. Once you set the percentage cells as italic etc, they should stay that way as you update - so no problems for the second part of your question. (you'll need to set the cells as % format too I think, otherwise will just transpose as a decimal)