# Set font on part of text (zh-CN, Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I've found question here about formatting part of cell, but colution not work at all (not sure if this is language related).

[Use different fonts in same Excel cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109644/use-different-fonts-in-same-excel-cell#)

`.text` below returns full text of cell, instead of signle character, so I can't check if text is western.

```
Sub TMP()
'
' TMP Macro
'
For i = 1 To ActiveCell.Characters.Count
    With ActiveCell.Characters(i)
    If InStr(1, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTQUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890", .Text) > 0     Then
        .Font.Name = Arial
    End If
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

Do you know any way around that glitch?

EDIT1:
I've checked another way for IF:

```
InStr(1, "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTQUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890", Mid(ActiveCell.Text, i, 1)) > 0
```

But it still not change `.font.name` property (but changes color if requested)

EDIT2:
I found where that glitch is: on merged cells. Didn't notice that I have them mixed with not merged. I bet that answer below will work with `Mid` if I will find way, to unmerge-merge cells with no visual effect.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Change all western ([a-z][A-Z][0-9]) characters font to Arial.

Comment: Use the 2nd argument of the `Characters` object to denote the number of characters you wish to return.  The `Name` of the font object should be a string.  Use the `Like` operator to do the comparison.  (See my answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Dim I As Long
For I = 1 To ActiveCell.Characters.Count
    With ActiveCell.Characters(I, 1)
        If .Text Like "[A-Za-z0-9]" Then
            .Font.Name = "Arial"
        End If
    End With
Next I
```